# Are transporters and cloaking devices compatible?

Tags: star-trek

I know phasers can't be used with cloaking devices; I was thinking it's the same for transporters but I'm not sure.

In the movie *Star Trek 3: The Search for Spock* a cloaked Klingon ship uses its transporter.  I think it's a mistake but I'm not sure.

Is there a source which can confirm or dispute this? Are transporters and cloaking devices compatible?

Comment: I think the trek-appropriate term is "transporter" rather than "teleporter".

Comment: I don't have a source, but I believe it's asymmetric; a transporter can work inside a cloak, just like their sensors can, but an outside transporter can't transport into a cloaked ship for the same reason it's not visible to sensors from outside.

Comment: IIRC the cloaking device worked through the shield system, which would suggest not, since they can't work through shields. Nevertheless, in addition to STIII as you mention, we also see people transported through a cloak in STIV.

Comment: I think I saw mentioned somewhere sometime that it's down to power requirements

Comment: @SpacePhoenix: I think you misspelled "plot" :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Star Trek IV The Voyage Home*, transporters are use multiple times in a cloaked Bird of Prey. It's not a writing mistake.
So, yes, transporters and cloaked devices are compatible.